# Using PRAGMAs as sources in SQLite in getting column names

Tags: sqlite, metadata

Problem:

I want to do this operation

`select name from pragma table_info(my_awesome_table)`

However, it yields a syntax error. I have the sneaking suspicion this is possible, but it doesn't seem to be documented as usable in the [SELECT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) docs with sqlite.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since SQLite 3.16.0 we can use [PRAGMA functions](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragfunc)

```
sqlite> create table my_table (a int, b TEXT);
sqlite> .headers ON
sqlite> .mode columns
sqlite> pragma table_info(my_table);
cid         name        type        notnull     dflt_value  pk
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0           a           int         0                       0
1           b           TEXT        0                       0
sqlite> select name from pragma_table_info('my_table');
name
----------
a
b
```

Comment: Just for closure on my part, can you offer any citations for that?

Comment: @Paul Nathan: `pragma-stmt` (http://sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#pragma-stmt) is used by `sql-stmt` only, as opposed to `select-stmt` (http://sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#select-stmt), definition of which is recursive.

Comment: It's an answer but it's not a solution.