# Is there an equivalent SELECT statement for PRAGMA table_info('mytable') in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

Is there an equivalent SELECT statement for PRAGMA table_info('mytable') in SQLite?  Essentially, I would like to get the exact same result set as PRAGMA returns: cid, name, type, notnull, dflt_value, and pk.  Although I know of the other alternative to getting this information via the C function sqlite3_table_column_metadata, I would prefer to use a SELECT statement.

Comment: I just found this post which is similar to my question, but it still doesn't answer my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899105/using-pragmas-as-sources-in-sqlite-in-getting-column-names

Answer (score 11):

According to the [doc](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html)

> PRAGMAs that return results and that have no side-effects can be
>   accessed from ordinary SELECT statements as table-valued functions.
>   For each participating PRAGMA, the corresponding table-valued function
>   has the same name as the PRAGMA with a 7-character "pragma_" prefix.
>   The PRAGMA argument and schema, if any, are passed as arguments to the
>   table-valued function.
>
> For example, information about the columns in an index can be read
>   using the index_info pragma as follows:
>
> PRAGMA index_info('idx52'); Or, the same content can be read using:
>
> SELECT * FROM pragma_index_info('idx52');

shouldn't this do the trick?

Comment: `sqlite> SELECT * FROM PRAGMA table_info(results);` returns error:
`Error: near "(": syntax error`

Comment: `sqlite> SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info('results');`  should work, note the spelling of `pragma_table_info` (with underline) and the table name should be within quotes